# How does PyNumber_Float handle an argument that is already a float?

Tags: type-conversion, python-c-api

Documentation for PyNumber_Float ([here](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/number.html#c.PyNumber_Float)) doesn't specify what happens if you pass in a PyObject* that points to another float.

e.g.
    PyObject* l = PyLong_FromLong( 101 );
    PyObject* outA = PyNumber_Float(l);

outA will point to a newly created float PyObject
(or if there already exists one with that value, I think it will point to that and just increment the reference counter)

However,

```
PyObject* f = PyFloat_FromDouble( 1.1 );
PyObject* outB = PyNumber_Float(f);
```

What happens here?

- Does it simply return the same pointer?
- Does it first increment the reference count and then return the same pointer?
- Or does it return a pointer to a new PyObject?

Is the behaviour guaranteed to be identical for the equivalent C-API calls for generating other primitives, such as Long, String, List, Dict, etc?

Finally, should the documentation clarify this situation? Would it be reasonable to file a doc-bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to haypo on the dev IRC channel, the following test shows that it returns the same object, with the reference counter incremented:

```
>>> x=1.1
>>> y=float(x)
>>> y is x, sys.getrefcount(x)-1, sys.getrefcount(y)-1
(True, 2, 2)

>>> y+=1
>>> y is x, sys.getrefcount(x)-1, sys.getrefcount(y)-1
(False, 1, 1)
```

*Note: explanation of why refcount is one-too-high [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302133/why-does-sys-getrefcount-return-2)*
*Note: x is y compares the memory address, "x is y" is the same as "id(x) == id(y)"*

Of course it is possible that some assignment-operator optimisation is bypassing the application of float()