# Detail on sys.getrefcount(a)

Tags: python

Given below snippet code in python Idle, why the `sys.getrefcount(a)` returns 4?

Given below snippet of code when executed in python idle

```
import sys
a = []
b = a
sys.getrefcount(a)            # returns 3
a
sys.getrefcount(a)            #returns 4
print(a)
sys.getrefcount(a)             #returns 3
```

Can anyone please explain why reference count gets increased to 4?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, it should be included in your question

Comment: All code needs to be posted here as text. And what were you expecting it to return?

Comment: @roganjosh m extremely sorry for not following the norms to post in the stackoverflow as I was unaware of it. I will keep this in mind from next time onwards.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @Carcigenicate Apologies for the mistake. As m new in the stackoverflow . I have edited the question. Can you explain me why the count of reference gets increased to 4 ?

Answer (score 6):

Let's count:

```
>>> import sys
>>> a = []
>>> sys.getrefcount(a)
2
```

We have two references, one under the name "a" and one argument to the function (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302133/why-does-sys-getrefcount-return-2)).

```
>>> b = a
>>> sys.getrefcount(a)
3
```

"a", "b", and the function arg.

```
>>> a
[]
>>> sys.getrefcount(a)
4
```

Where'd the fourth come from?  We're using the REPL, and in the repl we get a reference to the last (non-None) value under the name `_`:

```
>>> a
[]
>>> _
[]
```

If you add `print` around `sys.getrefcount(a)` and run it as a script, outside of the REPL (where there's no _ magic), you'll see 3.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce what you see in an interactive python shell. What happens is that when you do

```
>>> a
[]
```

you create an automatic reference in the variable `_` which always stores the value of the last unassigned expression. This is why after entering just `a` into your REPL you get an additional reference: `_` now points to the value `a`. I presume IDLE behaves the same way.