# sys.getrefcount() prints one more than the expected number of references to an object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reference

I would like to know why this code prints `4` instead of `3`. Where is the fourth reference?

```
import sys

def f(a):
    print(sys.getrefcount(a))

a = [1, 2, 3]
f(a)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does sys.getrefcount() return 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302133/why-does-sys-getrefcount-return-2)

Comment: If you get this as an audit question, put it as OK (if the wote count is still positive), not as the duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302133/why-does-sys-getrefcount-return-2 as I just did (even if it is almost a perfect duplicate...)

Comment: Interestingly, if you run it with Python 3.11, it prints `3`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can make sense of this in steps:

```
import sys

print(sys.getrefcount([1, 2, 3]))
# output: 1
```

```
import sys

a = [1, 2, 3]
print(sys.getrefcount(a))
# output: 2
```

```
import sys

def f(a):
    print(sys.getrefcount(a))

f([1, 2, 3])
# output: 3
```

```
import sys

def f(a):
    print(sys.getrefcount(a))

a = [1, 2, 3]
f(a)
# output: 4
```

So to reiterate:

- First reference is the global variable `a`
- Second reference is the argument passed to the `f` function
- Third reference is the parameter that the `f` takes
- Fourth reference is the argument passed to the `getrefcount` function

The reason for no fifth reference, from the parameter `getrefcount` takes, is that it's implemented in C, and those don't increase the reference count in the same way. The first example proves this, since the count is only 1 in that.

Comment: I know that, but if we count the references : a, the f's parameter, and the temporary reference given to getrefcount. That's three. Where is the fourth réference?

Comment: I know that they both count as one. 
I meant by `a` the global variable, the second reference is the `f`'s parameter, and the third reference is the `getrefcount`'s parameter. The question is why does this program print 4?

Comment: I don't understand! where is the fourth reference?

Comment: Thank you response. However, why do not count the formal parameter of `getrefcount` in line `12 POP_TOP` of the function like you did it in line `24 POP_TOP                         # 2. formal parameter`?

Comment: `co_names` isn't a reference to that object.

Comment: no, i'm very curious as well, but `co_names` is just a tuple of strings

Answer (score 1):

#### Update:

Python 3.11+ works differently now. You'll see `2` instead of `3` with this function:

```py
import ctypes

def get_ref_count(id_: int, un_used):   #  <----------
    return ctypes.c_long.from_address(id_).value

a = [1, 2, 3]
a_id = id(a)
print(get_ref_count(a_id, a))   # prints `2` instead of `3`.
```

---

I wanted to explain it a bit more. First I'm gonna use another method to get the number of references using it's `id`:

```py
import ctypes

def get_ref_count(id_: int):
    return ctypes.c_long.from_address(id_).value

a = [1, 2, 3]
a_id = id(a)
print(get_ref_count(a_id))   # 1
```

by just passing `a` as the argument of the `get_ref_count`, the count goes to 3.

```py
import ctypes

def get_ref_count(id_: int, un_used):   #  <----------
    return ctypes.c_long.from_address(id_).value

a = [1, 2, 3]
a_id = id(a)
print(get_ref_count(a_id, a))   # 3
```

See, I didn't actually do anything with `a`. But what happens?

When you call a funcion `fn(a)`, Python will load the `fn` and `a` and puts them on the stack. this is `LOAD_NAME` instruction. This instruction calls `Py_INCREF()` which increments the number of references by one. Then in order to call that function, it creates a *Frame object* and pass that reference as the [frame's local attribute](https://docs.python.org/3.12/c-api/frame.html#c.PyFrame_GetLocals) (Function's parameters are local variables of that function):

```py
from inspect import currentframe

def f(var):
    print(currentframe().f_locals)   # {'var': [1, 2, 3]}

a = [1, 2, 3]
f(a)
```

`f_locals` is exactly functions's local scope returned by `locals()`.

So that's why it incremented by 2.