# How is the popped value handled?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When value is popped off a dict:

1. Example of assignment: x = dict1.pop()

Here the popped value gets assigned to x. Is this pointer assignment or shallow or deep copy?

2. Example of no assignment: dict1.pop()

What happens to the popped value? Where does it go when no assignment is made?

Comment: 1) It's a regular assignment, like `n = 1; p = n; s = [];` and so on.

Comment: An object is subject to garbage collection once its reference count reaches 0. A popped value is no different.

Answer (score 2):

The `pop` method on a dictionary returns a reference to the actual value, not a copy of it: so `is` confirms that it's the same as the original value, by identity.

```py
>>> obj = object()
>>> d = {'foo': obj}
>>> d.pop('foo') is obj
True
```

If you don't assign the result or use it anywhere, then it's just silently discarded. You can observe using `sys.getrefcount` that there is one fewer reference to the value after popping it, since there is no longer a reference to it from the dictionary, and popping it without using the result somehow means no new reference is created:

```py
import sys

obj = object()
d = {'foo': obj}

print('Before popping:', sys.getrefcount(obj))

d.pop('foo')
print('After popping:', sys.getrefcount(obj))
```

Output (the refcount is inflated by 1 due to `getrefcount`'s parameter [also being counted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10302174/12299000)):

```
Before popping: 3
After popping: 2
```